# Using JavaScript to approve password length in an HTML POST form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web

I'm making a super basic website with simple login/logout and register functionality. On the register.php page, the user's chosen username and password are retrieved from the registration form via POST and stored in a mySQL database. I added JS to ensure that the password is at least 8 characters long, includes at least one number, and includes at least one capital letter.

The problem is, both the JS and PHP POST command execute when the user clicks the Submit button. How do I run the JS first and stop my script from processing and POSTing the form if my JS says that the user's password does not meet the minimum requirements?

**EDIT**: This is for a class project and we haven't learned Ajax. Can someone explain the process of 1) validating the password, 2) returning whether not the password is valid, 3) displaying (echoing?) a message if the password is invalid, and 4) proceeding with the form data POSTing if the password is valid? I know JavaScript is client-side and PHP is server-side, so I really don't understand how they're supposed to interact here.

Code below. As some commenters have pointed out, I am using post with the form.

```
  <form method="post" action="database.php"><fieldset><center>
      First Name  <input type='text' name='firstname' required><br><br>
      Last Name  <input type='text' name='lastname' required><br><br>
.
.
.
<input type='submit' value='Make My Account!'> <!-- Submit button -->
</center></fieldset></form>
```

Here's the JS I'm using to check for password length. I don't know how to do a POST command outside of a form. Also, inside the if/else block, should I be calling PHP functions?

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("password");
if(myInput.length()>8) {
  // post the form successfully
} else {
  // echo an error message
}
```

Comment: show the code also.

Comment: Kindly post your code then only we can help you.

Comment: Are you using a `submit` input? If so, change it to `button`, then in that, make a function call (onclick="validate()") with a return, **if true**, post the form, **false**, show errors.

Comment: Added code to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, its hard to know what is happening but I suspect you may have the form method set to 'post' which is sending your data to the server before the validation runs. An option is to have the validation of the password happen on the `blur` event. 
Also it would probably be best to use the fetch api or ajax to post your data to the server once everything has been validated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: `Also it would probably be best to use the fetch api or ajax to post your data to the server once everything has been validated.` I was about to say that.